# Selenium Webdriver 2.25.0 Java Firefox - Unable to identify Google Search Result Webelement

Tags: firefox, selenium, firebug, webdriver

I am a noob in Selenium 2.0 Java Webdriver. Trying to learn it by my own. But stuck at identifying a Webelement. I am trying to click on the search result of Google. I am searching by the string 'Selenium Download' and trying to click on the 1st outcome. It is identified as below in Firebug -

```
<a class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNF012aUD3cMR2x-qIQl2u6suxLnlw','','0CE0QFjAA',null,event)" href="http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fseleniumhq.org%2Fdownload%2F&ei=Wb8oULKfHsjsrAf4_IDICQ&usg=AFQjCNF012aUD3cMR2x-qIQl2u6suxLnlw">
<em>Downloads</em>
-
<em>Selenium</em>
</a>
```

XPath: /html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ol/li/div/h3/a

CSSPath: html body#gsr.vsh div#main div div#cnt.mdm div.mw div#rcnt div#center_col div#res.med div#search div#ires ol#rso li.g div.vsc h3.r a.l

But I have failed to identify this uniquely. I tried something like below -

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    WebDriver ffx1 = new FirefoxDriver();
    ffx1.get("http://www.google.com");
    ffx1.manage().window().maximize();
    ffx1.findElement(By.className("xbtn")).click();
    ffx1.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("saikat");
    ffx1.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    ffx1.findElement(By.xpath(My Expression));
```

}

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two things that need to be cleared out:

First - the locators you have are probably the incorrect ones
xpath for the first search element on google search page would be 
.//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/h3/a

Second - search results do take a couple of seconds to show up on the search results page after clicking the search button. Hence, some wait time must be inserted. I have used an implicit wait of 30 seconds in the code below. Implicit wait  will tell Webdriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

Now, if you try with the following code , it should work

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver ffx1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        ffx1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ffx1.get("http://www.google.com");
        ffx1.manage().window().maximize();
        ffx1.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("saikat");
        ffx1.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        ffx1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/h3/a")).click();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @StatusQuo! It did work :) But can I kindly request you to guide me more in identifying web-element. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: @SaikatSengupta, try learning more about HTML, CSS, javascript. http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-pick-identifiers.html , http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/